# изменение цены улучшения после нажатия кнопки

Tags: android

не могу придумать как сделать изменение "ценны улучшения" при нажатии на кнопку не увеличивая код в два раза , буду при много благодарен

```
//улучшения
   bt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (MainActivity.Cmoney >= 100){
            Money += 1;
            Cmoney -= 100;
            MainActivity.TMoney.setText(Cmoney + "");
        }
   });
```

Comment: непонятно, что вам нужно?

Comment: нужно что бы значение (MainActivity.Cmoney >= 100) увеличивалось на 100 после нажатия на кнопку

Comment: а чем вас ваш код не устраивает?

Comment: в моём коде улучшение всегда стоит 100 нужно что бы оно менялось.

Answer (score 0):

Если цену нужно устновить единоразово, то сделайте так

```
final int cost = getCost(); //установите цену здесь
bt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
     if (MainActivity.Cmoney >= cost){
         Money += 1;
         Cmoney -= cost;
         MainActivity.TMoney.setText(Cmoney + "");
     }
});
```

Если при каждом нажатии, то так

```
bt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
     final int cost = getCost(); //установите цену здесь
     if (MainActivity.Cmoney >= cost){
         Money += 1;
         Cmoney -= cost;
         MainActivity.TMoney.setText(Cmoney + "");
     }
});
```

Comment: Вот что получилось 
    'bt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            final int cost = getСost(100); //установите цену здесь
            if (Cmoney >= cost){
                Money += 1;
                Cmoney -= cost;
                MainActivity.TMoney.setText(Cmoney + "");
            }
        });'
Но метод getCost это ошибка , я решмл создать метод 
'private int getcost(int i) {
        return +100;
    }'
Безуспешно

Comment: да, getCost метод нужно реализовать, из вопроса непонятно как вы хотите его сделать, поэтому он приведён в качестве абстракции, что этот метод возвращает нужную вам цену